# HTML: <input> element changes position after user input

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-position, user-input

I am building a web-based, self-quizzing application, but I'm having some troubles out of my input form. I have it structured such that each input element has its own cell in a table. I'm including a picture for reference. The table alternates columns of numbers and input elements. I did this mainly for ease of aesthetic structure.

[image]

Unfortunately, those aesthetics are messed up whenever a user enters a string into the input element. The elements move closer to the bottom of the page once a user has entered a string and then tabbed to the next input element. I'm including another picture for reference.

[image]

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this error? I'm happy to update with any details necessary concerning the markup, css, or jQuery.

Comment: Link to the site or a jsfiddle with the error might help. But here is a wild guess, the input has some css property for `:focus` which is causing the top margin?

Comment: @SwashataGhosh , it does have a :focus added to it, but the only things that get altered are the background-color, outline, and box-shadow. I'm developing on my localhost, so I'm not sure if I could fit everything on jsfiddle.

Comment: What browser do you use?

Comment: @AndriyF. I've been developing in Chrome on Mac OSX.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit seems to be

```
vertical-align: baseline;
```

in CSS

Comment: Wow. That worked swimmingly. I always looked at CSS normalize as returning everything to an empty default state. Never thought I would CREATE a css problem from CSS normalize. What does that line actually do?

Comment: baseline
Aligns the baseline of the element with the baseline of its parent. The baseline of some replaced elements, like <textarea> is not specified by the HTML specification, meaning that their behavior with this keyword may change from one browser to the other. (MDN)

Comment: PS: quite nice normalize.css is used in HTML Boilerplate